# Disable Ember's MANDATORY_SETTER requirement for external lib

Tags: javascript, ember.js, paperjs

I have a view in my Ember application. In the `didInsertElement` function I'm trying to initialize a Paper.JS object on a defined canvas.

```
didInsertElement: function() 
{
  //ENV.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES = false;

  // setup paper.js
  var paperScope = new paper.PaperScope();
  paperScope.setup(this.get("controller").get("canvas"));

  //ENV.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES = true;

  this.set("paper", paperScope);
}
```

However, Ember throws the following error:

`You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object HTMLCanvasElement])` on the `paperScope.setup()` line.

It happens because the Paper.js `setup()` method tries to set a property (`element.width = ...`) on the canvas without using Ember's `set()` method:

```
_setViewSize: function(size) {
    var width = size.width,
        height = size.height,
        pixelRatio = this._pixelRatio,
        element = this._element,
        style = element.style;
    element.width = width * pixelRatio;
    element.height = height * pixelRatio;
    (...)
},
```

The following possibilities could maybe circumvent the problem:

- adapt ember.js to ignore the MANDATORY_SETTER requirement in the Paper.JS setup method
- adapt paper.js to use the `Ember.set(element, key, value)` method on the canvas object (by directly changing the Paper.JS code, or by providing a mock Canvas object that defers the relevant calls?)
- turn off Ember's MANDATORY_SETTER requirement and rewrite all my code according to http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/

but I would rather find something more simple/elegant.

What is the best way to be able to use Paper.JS with Ember.js and the MANDATORY_SETTER setting?

Comment: what is this.get("controller").get("canvas"), and where is it set?

Comment: I'm not seeing that happen, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jipezu/1/edit

Comment: That's probably because I have two computed properties on the canvas in the controller:

canvasWidth: function() {
    return this.get(CANVASTYPE.DEFAULT).width;
  }.property(CANVASTYPE.DEFAULT + ".width"),
  
  canvasHeight: function() {
    return this.get(CANVASTYPE.DEFAULT).height;
  }.property(CANVASTYPE.DEFAULT + ".height"),